Accuracy of CNN model starts from 0.96 and descends slowly instead of increasing over epoch
The thing is, my cnn model for some reason instead of having increased accuracy over each epoch, decreases from 0.95 in the start slowly settling around 0.85. For instance, in first epoch it goes from 0.96 to 0.80, in second epoch at the start is on 0.95 and settles around 0.81 and so o until it settles around 0.85
What i tried: changing data augmentation parameters, changing learning rate, adding dropout layers.
My data is being trained on 600 ish images 400 of them being fire images and the rest non fire
my code is follwoing
`project_path = "C:\\Users\\immaf\\Desktop\\Extended essay" 

images = []
labels = []
for subfolder in os.listdir(project_path):
    print(f"Processing folder: {subfolder}")  # Print folder name for debugging
    
    subfolder_path = os.path.join(project_path, subfolder)
    if not os.path.isdir(subfolder_path):
        continue

    # List images in the folder
    for image_filename in os.listdir(subfolder_path):
        image_path = os.path.join(subfolder_path, image_filename)
        images.append(image_path)
        labels.append(subfolder)

# Create DataFrame
data = pd.DataFrame({'image': images, 'label': labels})
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 10)

# Split the data into training (70%), validation (15%), and test (15%)
train_data, temp_data = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.3, random_state=42, stratify=data['label'])
val_data, test_data = train_test_split(temp_data, test_size=0.5, random_state=42, stratify=temp_data['label'])
batch_size = 32
image_size = (256, 256)
# Training data generator with augmentation
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1.0/255,  # Rescale pixel values to [0, 1]
    rotation_range=20,  # Randomly rotate images
    width_shift_range=0.05,  # Randomly shift images horizontally
    height_shift_range=0.05,  # Randomly shift images vertically
    zoom_range=0.05,  # Randomly zoom into images
    horizontal_flip=True,  # Randomly flip images
    fill_mode='nearest'  # Fill in newly created pixel
)


# Validation and test data generator (only rescaling)
val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255)


# Create generators for training, validation, and test sets
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=train_data,
    x_col='image',
    y_col='label',
    target_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',  # Use 'categorical' for multi-class classification
    shuffle=True,
)
val_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=val_data,
    x_col='image',
    y_col='label',
    target_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=test_data,
    x_col='image',
    y_col='label',
    target_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary'
)
from tensorflow.keras import models, layers
learning_ratee = 0.0001  # Adjust learning rate
filter_size = (3, 3)  # Size of the convolution filters
num_filters = 32  # Number of filters in the first Conv2D layer
dropout_rate = 0.5  # Dropout rate
pooling_layer_type = 'max'  # 'max' or 'average' pooling
strides = 1  # Stride for the convolutional layers

# Create the model
model = models.Sequential()

# First convolutional layer
model.add(layers.Conv2D(num_filters, filter_size, strides, activation='relu', input_shape=(256, 256, 3)))

# Add pooling layer
#if pooling_layer_type == 'max':
  #  model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
#elif pooling_layer_type == 'average':
   # model.add(layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# Second convolutional layer
#model.add(layers.Conv2D(num_filters * 2, filter_size, strides=strides, activation='relu'))  # Double the filters for deeper layers
#if pooling_layer_type == 'max':
  #  model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
#elif pooling_layer_type == 'average':
model.add(layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# Third convolutional layer
model.add(layers.Conv2D(num_filters * 4, filter_size, strides=strides, activation='relu'))  # Increase filters
#if pooling_layer_type == 'max':
   # model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
#elif pooling_layer_type == 'average':
model.add(layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# Flattening the output
model.add(layers.Flatten())

# Fully connected layer
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))

# Dropout layer
model.add(layers.Dropout(dropout_rate))

# Output layer
# Change from binary classification to multi-class classification
num_classes = 2
model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))  # Replace num_classes with the actual number of classes


# Compile the model with binary crossentropy with specified learning rate
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_ratee),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',  # Change to binary crossentropy
              metrics=['accuracy'])


# Model summary to check the structure
model.summary()
print(f"Total training samples: {len(train_data)}")
print(f"Batch size: {batch_size}")
print(f"Steps per epoch: {len(train_data) // batch_size}")
history = model.fit(
    train_generator,           # Training data generator
    validation_data=val_generator,  # Validation data generator
    epochs=32,                 # Number of epochs
    callbacks=[]               # Any callbacks (if needed)
)


`

Also i have a question whether the following distortions in data augmentations okay? ( They were more severe before i smoothed them 
